# Obtain web data with app script for sites requiring logging in first

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to obtain some data from http://www.cinedi.com by my google script to put it in my spreadsheet.but imust log in first !
With UrlFetchApp, I know how to extract data from the web to feed my Google spreadsheets on allocine.fr for example. I can't do this for sites where you have to log in first. For example cinedi.com in my case. Despite my research and testing, I'm having trouble getting there. Taking inspiration from https://gist.github.com/baileymatthewr/197179eb2b9340f2a47a9b9be019c214 I tested the following code but I only get the login page.

```
function fetchMethod(url="http://www.cinedi.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx",login="mylogin",password="mypass"){
    var params;
    params = {method: "POST", headers: {"ctl00$Content$TbxLogin":login,"ctl00$Content$TbxPassword":password}};
    // i tried with no success thoses differents options . I don't know they use
    //params = {method: "POST", headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(ctl00$Content$TbxLogin + ":" +ctl00$Content$TbxPassword)}};
    //params = {method: "POST", headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + Utilities.base64Encode(ctl00$Content$TbxLogin + ":" +ctl00$Content$TbxPassword)}};
    //params = {method: "POST", headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
    //params = {method: "POST", headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText()); //Log the download in the Google Script Logger
  //DriveApp.createFile("file_name_of_your_choice", response); //Download the file to Google Drive.
}
```

Who could put me on the right track?
Even if it is with another site for the example
Big thanks !!

The html code of the home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title>
    Cinedi.com v1.19.07.6
</title><link href="css/cinedi.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>
    <!--
...

    -->
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTk4MjQwOTE5Mw8WAh4TVmFsaWRhdGVSZXF1ZXN0TW9kZQIBFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIODxUBKQ0KICAgICAgICAgIDxwPkZPIENFR0VESU08L3A+DQogICAgICAgICAgZGQu4FBOkgas66ryde+qSeR7Kugnt8og001iyuaLH2n2pA==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=R2COHET1vXyEOho_Os_sD5F2NGP2tljpk89yFgY8vXbjlSnnonSEEtMYsbWhO95kgb049hqsjHVp4Mv94I8biINB7LHlB1tVNduZea_VvCU1&amp;t=638259434771233176" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=0YtutSDCthKsJs-R1atnoq8XcqngK92IQ0_fJ0SarHOrDHwyJaDZM3XD7embmRVHjne7CK05nrYQJrobWMSjJfntd_JJtYYsBdA_mmUv6841&amp;t=638259434771233176" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="C2EE9ABB" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAARW36i1U0bnpy022hdmTErgjNybpmlHrx+LLB+9QARqWCM6CSWaLjOKRFloHKQpIqDlBvHk9Km87ntRGzOC/Hqv5kzh6XXXCWL9EF3sgBNmxSl73BjoOAK5/3h3FrFevYw=" />
</div>
    <div id="head">
        <div class="logologin">
            <a href="/">            
                    <img alt="CNC" style="border:0px" src="img/head/CNC_logo.png" />
                    <img class="titre" alt="cinedi.com" style="border:0px" src="img/head/titre.png" />       
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="menu0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
            
    <div id="login">
        <div class="bienvenue">
            
            <div class="validation">                        
                <table class="login">
                    <caption>Identification</caption>
                    <col width="*"/>
                    <col width="1%"/>               
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2">                      
                            <span class="soustitre">Veuillez saisir votre identifiant et votre mot de passe</span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>                 
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="ctl00_Content_TbxLogin" id="ctl00_Content_LbxLogin">Utilisateur</label></th>
                            <td><input name="ctl00$Content$TbxLogin" type="text" id="ctl00_Content_TbxLogin" style="width:150px;" /></td>                   
                        </tr><tr>
                            <th><label for="ctl00_Content_TbxPassword" id="ctl00_Content_LbxPassword">Mot de passe</label></th>
                            <td><input name="ctl00$Content$TbxPassword" type="password" id="ctl00_Content_TbxPassword" style="width:150px;" /></td>
                        </tr>                   
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><a class="right" href="ChangePassword.aspx">Changement du mot de passe</a></td></tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>                        
                <div class="bouton_barre right">
                    <div class="bouton">
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$Content$BtnLogin" value="OK" id="ctl00_Content_BtnLogin" class="bouton" />
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="avertissement">
        <p>Ce site est à usage restreint. Si vous n'avez pas d'identifiant, ou bien si vous l'avez perdu, contactez votre agent CNC qui vous en communiquera un nouveau.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="aide">
        <p class="titre">Aide</p>
         
          <p>FO CEGEDIM</p>
          
    </div>
 
    

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
WebForm_AutoFocus('ctl00_Content_TbxLogin');//]]>
</script>
</form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    xtnv = document;
    xtsd = "http://logi162";
    xtsite = "0";
    xtn2 = "";        // level 2 site
    xtpage = "Login.aspx";        //page name (with the use of :: to create chapters)
    xtdi = "";        //implication degree
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/xtcore.js"></script>
    <noscript>
    <img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="http://logi162.xiti.com/hit.xiti?s=0&s2=&p=&di=&" >
    </noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: Depends on how the login is done, you should probably do two fetches. First fetch the login page, ``get`` all the input names, values, then ``post`` it, stimulating a form submit, get the retrieved tokens, cookies and any other things needed and then make the next `get` request with the authenticated cookies...

Comment: Thank you TheMaster ! :)
For the first step i tried to adapt my code relatively to the html code of the home page that i adding in my original post